# XAMPP internal server error

Tags: localhost, xampp

Currently i am working on a wordpress website on xamp local server and i have changed some settings in the website URL from `localhost/websitename` to `localhost/websitename/home` and i got the following error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to
>   inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.10 Server at localhost
>   Port 80

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where did you made this change? please elaborate.

Comment: Add this line in wp-config and you wlill get issue

Comment: define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

Comment: So i made some settings in the console panel/settings (website URL from localhost/websitename to localhost/websitename/home) because just right after i tried to use polylang localhost/websitename URL showed a blank site, but i found my full built site on localhost/websitename/home URL.

Comment: so since i have made the changes in the URL (console panel/settings) i get the same internal server error when i try to reach localhost/websitename/home

Comment: Pratikb.Simform - define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); did not work unfortunatelly